# How to keep &nbsp without empty space?

Tags: html, css, text, fonts

I have small problem with my text. In some part of text I'm using '&nbsp' to make sure, that specific word will not break(or move) to new line. So for example I did something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit ammet -&nbsp;is not a joke!
```

So theoretically, this text('- is') shouldn't end up on a new line as a single word, right? I guess that's right.
But... That technique brings me one issue which is additional big empty space between "-" and "is"... And of course I don't want to have that "big empty space". I'll give You example of that result:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit ammet -  is not a joke!
```

As You can see, there is a huge space. So, my question is - how to get rid of that space, but also stick to my target assumption which is "Don't brake '- is' word to the new line as a single word."
Is there any technique to use &nbsp without additional space?

Comment: A non-breaking space just tells the line breaking mechanism not to break on that specific space. In your example, it won't break the line between the hyphen and "is".  It may break the line before the hyphen and after "is". The assumption "Don't brake [sic] '- is' word to the new line as a single word" is actually exactly opposite to the effect of using a non-breaking space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, try:

```
white-space:break-spaces
```

Comment: with '&nbsp'? Or remove '&nbsp' and add "white-space:break-spaces"?

Answer (score 1):

use Semi-Space
it is same as space but not break the line
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other-mso_2007/half-space-semi-space-between-words/75bfe733-fe45-47c8-a935-88ffb8848098